# Theme a specific block id

Tags: 6, blocks

I am looking for a simple and effective way to implement template for specific block IDs.

From what I read in [Author information lost after saving node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/author-information-lost-after-saving-node) and [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642), I came up with the following code, which doesn't seem to work:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) { 
  array_unshift($vars['template_files'], 'block-' . $vars['region'] . '-' .   filter_xss($vars['id'])); 
}
```

From the Drupal documentation it should block-module-delta.tpl.php.

- Delta is the block ID, that's ok
- Module? What's the module here it's a custom block created by adding a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Firebug to inspect the generated HTML to get the block name|module !

Comment: Ok, firebug gives a block id of 'block-block-19' so i put a file named 'block-block-19.tpl.php' but didn't work.

Comment: Oh, I had block theme enabled which caused to bypass my template suggestion. Works fine now ! Thanks !

Comment: From http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7
Try: block--block--19.tpl.php

Comment: just for the record block-block-19.tpl.php AND block--block--19.tpl.php actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the skinr module? http://drupal.org/project/skinr

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRsbVguQ7b4

You can add classes to particular blocks and reuse styles. This can be very helpful if you're using a grid system or any of the grid themes.